# Finding batteries to make a stable 12 V battery-power supply

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator

I want to make a stable 12 V battery-power supply for RPi and LED matrix. Schematic is something like:

```
Battery -> 12 V regulator (- > 5 V regulator, just in case) -> RPi
                 |
            LED matrix
```

To supply a stable voltage source, a regulator is required and then battery should have voltage higher than 12 V due to dropout voltage.

I live in Korea. And batteries equal to or less than 12 V can be seen easily but and I cannot find such batteries in Korean electronic parts shop. Yet, I can find 24 V battery, but I think it's too much. Therefore, the only choice I can make is to put small batteries into series to provide appropriate voltage.

An Easiest way is to put 9 or 10 1.5 V batteries into series to get 13.5 or 15 V, but I doubt whether there is a battery holder that can contain 10 batteries. Another way is 6 + 9 V, but I think it has a disadvantage for modularizing since they might have different size and shape.

Is there any good idea to deal with it? I hope that the size of battery isn't too big for RPi and LED matrix.

Is a solution like below the best? (12 V / 10,000 mAh module from web)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You speak of dropout voltages, which makes me think you are planning to use a pair of linear regulators for this, such as a 7812 and a 7805.

At idle, a Pi draws about 0.4 A.<sup>1</sup> P=VI, so you're talking about burning up 7 × 0.4 = 2.8 W across the second regulator.<sup>2</sup> That's a fair bit of waste.

A bare TO-220 regulator has a 50°C/W thermal resistance, and 50 × 2.8 comes to 140°C over ambient. Ambient temperature will only be as low as 20-25°C indoors, and then only if you're running this device naked on the workbench with a fan blowing on it. Unless your final application will have this thing running in a ventilated case outside in winter, count on the actual ambient temperature to be higher as the electronics heat up the air inside the case.

The second regulator is almost certain to destroy itself if you don't put a fairly big heat sink on it.

But it gets worse.

The first regulator will also be producing heat, up to about 5 W worth of it.<sup>3</sup> The heat sinks on both regulators will have to be bigger than you calculate for each alone, since they will each be heating up the air inside the electronics' enclosure. The dual regulator system will come to an equilibrium higher than if you were running the two regulators in separate enclosures.

A far superior solution is to use one of the many off-the-shelf DC-DC converters that will put out both 5 and 12 V from a single input supply. You will find that there are models covering a wide range of input voltages. Any battery that can put out enough current for your job can be made to work.

When you start stringing many cells together into a high-voltage battery, you make it much easier for the battery to kill itself due to cell reversal. The fewer the cells you can use in series, the better. Another of the advantages of the DC-DC converter solution is that you can find types that will put out more voltage than they take in,<sup>4</sup> so you could get away with just 1-4 cells, which is less likely to self-destruct.

You might be able to avoid the requirement for a regulated 12 V supply. LEDs don't really want constant voltage, they want constant *current*. The EE 101 way to get that is to drop a constant voltage across a fixed resistor, but there are [a whole lot of ways to make a constant current source/sink](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=constant+current+source). So, you'd put the CCS either between the raw supply voltage and the LED array or between the LED array and ground, then run the Pi from a 5 V DC-DC converter.

---

**Footnotes:**

1. It can go [way up from there](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5068).
2. The second regulator only sees the 12-to-5 V drop, due to the way you've drawn your system in the question. Thus, we can ignore the battery voltage question for this part of the analysis.
3. The first regulator throws off even more heat than the first, for a couple of reasons.

   First, the battery can't drop below 12 V+V<sub>d</sub>, the regulator's dropout voltage, if we're going to meet your "stable voltage" requirement.

   To get the full use out of the battery, you want to divide a single cell's lowest useful voltage into the lowest battery voltage you can tolerate to get the minimum number of cells. Then you multiply that by the *highest* voltage of the battery to get the peak battery voltage.

   NiMH cells are still the most DIY-friendly sort. NiMH cells range from about 1.35 V when fresh off the charger down to about 0.8 V when nearly dead. If we use a regulator with a 2 V dropout voltage, we divide 0.8 into (12+2) V, which comes to 17.5 cells, which we have to round up to 18 × 1.35 V = 24.3 V. That means the first regulator could be throwing off another 12.3 × 0.4 = 5 W!

   As the battery voltage drops, heat thrown off the the first regulator will also drop, unlike heat produced by the second regulator, which sees a constant voltage. It only drops to about 4 W, though, so it does't really change our conclusions.

   Lithium rechargeables differ on behavior from NiMH a fair bit, but if you run the same calculations on them, the conclusions don't change much.

   But all of that only considers the heat due to the Pi's power draw. You also have to add the current required by your LED matrix, which you haven't specified. If it's another 400 mA, you double the power wasted in the first regulator.
4. At a cost of higher input current.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you will want to use a DC-DC switching regulator for thermal (power dissipation) reasons - if not for efficiency (battery life). The right kind of regulator (boost) can provide an output voltage higher than the input voltage, so you needn't worry about finding a battery > 12V - as long as the battery is rated to provide sufficient power. Compared to a linear regulator, a switching converter will be somewhat more complicated to configure, but it needn't be so bad if you find a simple one. You will need an inductor and a few capacitors in addition to an IC.

Consider running the LED from a (switching) LED driver to control the current into them and then use a separate DC-DC to derive the 5V for the rPi. That way you can debug or replace them each separately, if required.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to think differently. The led matrix will work very well from 11.5V as well.

A battery is considered being totally over-discharged if its output voltage is below 11V, so if you go with a 12V battery then you don't need a 12V regulator at all.

If you need more runtime, consider a battery with higher mAh rating.

Regarding to the PI, consider using a switching regulator, otherwise you'll waste serious power. The simplest thing is to buy a car usb adapter (goes to the cigarette lighting socket, and gives you a clean 5V USB output), and you have the switching buck regulator ready.

I would avoid of using any boost regulator unless you are seriously in need for those. Making 12V from a lower voltage battery with boost regulator has no advantage, it is introducing at least 10% of loss. To have the same run time, even the battery weight will be the same, i.e. 12V 1000mAh battery vs. 6V 2000mAh battery.